# LINQ where does not return expected values

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

Why is the following snippet not returning the expected result?

```
List<string[]> data
//filling list with some values (left here out to make problem more clear)

var allRowsHavingSomeWordWithLengthGreaterThanFive = (from d in data
                         from c in d
                         where c.Length > 5
                         select d);
```

data is a List containing an array which contains strings in each row.

This statement returns null.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @BrokenGlass do i need a join? As you can see there is also the second from clause: "from c in d" which should do the joining ... or am i wrong?

Comment: How does leaving out the values make this *more* clear? It seems as though the values are central to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is perfect as it's. I don't know why it shouldn't work.

You could make it a little easier as:

```
var allRowsHavingSomeWordWithLengthGreaterThanFive = 
         from d in data
         where d.Any(q => q.Length > 5)
         select d;
```

But I don't see why.

Perhaps the problem is that there are `null` `string`s or `null` `string[]`?

```
var allRowsHavingSomeWordWithLengthGreaterThanFive = (from d in data
                                                      where d != null
                                                      from c in d
                                                      where c != null && c.Length > 5
                                                      select d).ToArray();
```

See tester http://ideone.com/ci8zw1

Comment: @ xanatos Thanks for the quick response! But i'm talking about linq for Objects (not having a DB access)

Answer (score 0):

Xanatos is right... It's about the Null values..  Should have noticed earlier.
A simple null check is enough:

```
from d in data
from c in d
where c!=null &&  c.Length > 5
select d
```